# Fama and French HML and SMB factors

Tags: finance, asset-pricing, fama-french, factor-investing

I am investigating the Fama and French model using a Bayesian selection procedure laid out by Barillas and Shanken (2018). When I plot the cumulative probabilities of each factor, I notice that for both HML and SMB these probabilities decrease sharply. What is a possible explanation for this effect? Is it due to the dot-com bubble? If so why?

[image]